# could cobalt playback 4k content?

Tags: cobalt

we built cobalt( fd76734 - Import Cobalt 8.21796) by "linux-x64x11" successfully and we can playback Youtube content fine.

then we try to playback 4K content, it can work fine also.
next, we enable "env_isVideoInfoVisible=1", cobalt will show video infotmation. 

we change "video_pixel_ratio" to fit 3840*2160 also and rebulid cobalt.

then we check the content resolution, cobalt never up to 3840x2160. the toppest resolution is 1920x1080.
our testing video id is "6_P8RUqGQbM" but it seems any title has same result.

can someone help us to playback real 4k content?

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt can play 4k content, but for > FHD YouTube content, you need to support the VP9 codec, which the Linux Desktop Starboard implementation doesn't currently do. It just uses FFMPEG for software H.264 decoding.

The SbPlayer implementation will need to report support for VP9 in SbMediaCanPlayMimeTypeAndKeySystem(), and then you should be able to get 4k content from YouTube.